# react-native-video controls in notification center

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-video

I am developing a `react-native-video` app and I need to display the video controls in the notification center on Android and iOS.

I am using `5.3.1-alpha.3` version and from what I've seen while researching the subject, many developers say that `react-native-video` does not have support to this feature yet.

I've seen some developers talking about `react-native-track-player` since it already has this feature, but changing the player is not an option. Is there any compatibility between them?

If there is no compatibility, is it possible to do this via native modules or a notification package (ex. Notifee)?

If you have any opinion, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me know if you find something.

Comment: @FaisalShaik I used [react-native-music-control](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-music-control). Despite being archived, it worked well for me.

Comment: it worked with video ? or you use this package only for notification control ?

Comment: @FaisalShaikh it works with video. Now I can control the video play/pause with earphones and can skip back and forward in the notification control